# How can I expand buffer space or slow down gsutil upload speed?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I'm trying to upload some files to google cloud storage.

No problem when the upload speed is about 2MiB/s.

But if the upload speed is about 9~10MiB/s, gsutil stopped and left this error, "[Errno 55] No buffer space available".

So, I'm looking for the solutions expanding buffer space or slowing down upload speed.

How can I do?

Comment: What OS are you using? The error message indicates network buffers somewhere are not being released, which I suspect is not being caused by gsutil (since I've never seen that error reported from any other gsutil user). See also https://serverfault.com/questions/131935/network-error-no-buffer-space-available

Comment: I'm using macOS. So, killing some processes can be a solution? @MikeSchwartz

Comment: I use gsutil on MacOS, so I don't think it's a bug in the OS network handling (which was why I was asking about OS). It's possible some other processes are not releasing network buffers but I would be careful about just killing processes unless you know what they do. One thing you could try is to boot in Safe Mode (which will load a minimal set of kernel extensions etc.) and try running gsutil. If the problem doesn't happen in Safe Mode it indicates something in the delta between Safe and normal mode is what's not releasing buffers.